# How to establish a relationship between tables in SQLite on Visual Studio for Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I am creating a multiplatform application and using a SQLite database. From what I understand SQLite does not support utilizing foreign keys to create a relationship between tables. How would one go about establishing a relationship if this is not an option?

Comment: You don't need a formal constraint like foreign keys to join on columns between tables. Even in other database systems you can join anything on anything. Just write your logic the way you need it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That makes sense, I'll think on that